# Excel Hyperlink within the same sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets.   Sheet1 and Sheet2.  I want to stay on sheet1 and create a hyperlink to sheet2 but I want the information that is available in sheet2 to be displayed in sheet1 itself once I click the link...  how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: sounds like you want an "on-hover" type action. You'll need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

`Camera` might be a solution for you.  Instead of hyperlink, you can place a `camera` window that will show your data in sheet2.  This will be a live camera, meaning you will see any changes in sheet2 immediately as it happens.

[image]